# Checking text of button in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Im making a tic-tac-toe game and i need to check if the button text is 'X' or 'O' so i can check if there is a winner. Is there any way for me to do this?
I tried this just as a random guess to see how it works:

```
if button1.config(text='X'):
    #x_won = True
else:
    pass
```

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the buttons text by `button1['text']` or any other of the buttons keys.

You can see the keys for the button by doing `button1.keys()`

You can check `if button1['text'] == 'X':` etc

Using `button.config(text='X')` is setting the buttons text to be `X` not checking for equality.

Comment: Is there a way to do what you did with the "if" statement without passing it an actual button name?

Comment: @Mike What you're asking doesn't make sense.... I accessed a class and an attribute of the class (in this case a component of a widget...). You can grab all widgets in a frame using `winfo_children` if I recall and iterate and check, but not all widgets have the same attributes. There are other roundabout ways...